# Is what I mentioned here on text is a disbelief?

Tags: sin, kufr

Long ago at age of 15, thelast night I was a Christian, my Muslim father asked me who was the last prophet?

I answered him Jesus,then my father asked one more,who is the last prophet?

I replayed: I don't know,you know.

And he said that's because your a Christian and he answered: prophet Muhammad is the last prophet, and then I asked him: huh? How do u know? There are many prophets back in history.

And he said:You always think of the last prophet.

Then my Muslim father asked me:Do you want to become a Muslim?

And I replayed: No,because I'm not ready for it.

And he said that's no problem you can learn what other Muslims know things.

And as a replay I said: No.

And he said you don't know what is good for you. Then when I went back to sleep, I asked God to forgive me that I did not want to become and then I said in my mind:No no,tomorrow I will show to my father that I know what is good for me, and my feelings told me that go ahead ask your father how to become a Muslim and next day I asked him: How can I become a Muslim

He answered by saying: There is no God but one God and Muhammad is God's prophet,and then I repeated after him.

I then asked him if I can say on my mother language(Romanian): Nu exista niciun alt Dumnezeu decât unu iar profetul este Muhamed.

And my father said to me: Finish,congratulations,you have become a Muslim.Am I considered as a disbeliever what I mentioned in this text?

Just to know

Comment: You now believe Allah is the only true god , and Muhammad is his messenger. So you are a Muslim .  Denying or doubting that Muhammad is the last prophet of God : is a disbelief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Am I considered as a disbeliever" - No.

From your description, on that last night... you were displaying ignorance at best or rejection of the Prophet Muhammad (disbelief) at worst. **BUT,** everything you described here happened before you accepted Islam. Once you accepted Islam, then your entire slate was wiped clean of all sins and disbelief. It is going forward from there that it starts counting. So your actions on that last night before you accepted Islam don't affect your status as a Muslim now. :)

Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) said, "Islam wipes out whatever sins came before it" - Ahmad (17159).

Comment: So it is ok if I made a haram thing or a sin then I can use the testimony of faith to wipe out all sins including haram things?I have also intention to be wiped out all sins,is it ok?Acceptable?

Comment: Coz if I did a disbelief or shirk without me to know then I can use this in case of everything?Night after night?

Comment: The phenomenon of testimony of faith wiping out sins applies when going from disbeliever-to-believer status, not for when you are already a Muslim. For Muslims, you just repent. Repenting from sins sincerely erases them. Night after night, you can sincerely repent and ask Allah (ﷻ) to forgive all your sins, intentional and unintentional, and this would be acceptable.

Comment: Ok,I understand

Comment: And if I want to ask God Almighty to forgive me I say stahfurila?

Comment: How can you write on telephone,like when you write for example prophet Muhammad( )said I don't know what.How do you write that thing from brackets?Curious to know coz when I write in brackets I use like this(pbuh)but in Arabic?I don't know this

Comment: Yes. You do that (ie, ask for forgiveness) and you also regret the sin and make intention to never return to it again. This all is part of repentance.

Comment: As for the telephone thing.. Idk. Sorry. I just copy/paste from my laptop. Maybe you can copy/paste from your phone? :)

Comment: One thing,If I had in mind to say a disbelief thing and then before I say I think 2x before I regret and I don't say it,I keep my mouth shut,then this will no longer be counted?

Comment: It won't be counted. :) If we get evil thoughts but we regret them and never utter them, then we get good deeds. Alhamdulillah.

Comment: And it doesn’t matter if I say shahada in Romanian language as I mentioned in text? Because, when I say “Dumnezeu” or “Doamne”, I refer strict to Allah, not to Jesus, not to anybody. And when I say “Doamne...”, this is like making a supplication Allah which is actually true even though I don’t use the word Allah, I use another word to call upon Him which is Doamne, so Doamne, is like when you say, O Allah, so it is the same, and Dumnezeu means Allah. So, I can make Du’a to Allah by saying Doamne? Out of curiosity.